# Chrome extension external url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Google Chrome Extension. This worked for me:

```
{
"name": "Test",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Test",
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["a.js"]
 }
]

}
```

But when trying to load the .js from an external URL, I can't install the extension.

```
{
"name": "Test",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Test",
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["http://EXTERNALURL.com/a.js"]
 }
]

}
```

Can I solve this issue by giving "permission" to load from EXTERNALURL.com, or can't this be achieved at all? Does the file have to be local?

I hope you can help me out in order to plan my extension from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot make Chrome load an extension from an external URL. Bundle your JS in the extension and use automatic updates if you need to change it.